# MDT "A connection to the deployment share could not be made" message Solution

Tags: wds, mdt

I am using Windows server 2016, and MDT v6.3.8456.1000, ADK Windows 10 1809 and 
suddenly I started experiencing this error, although settings in BootStrap.ini are correct, and I have already updated the deploy share with "Completely regenerate the boot images" option.

I was also sure about the fact that all shares all accessible!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue is as follows, which is very strange, open the following registry locations on (WDS/MDT are on the same OS) server:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Services\LanmanServer\Shares
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Services\LanmanServer\Shares\Security
```

Delete all entries except `REMINST` and open powershell, run the following:

```
Restart-Service -Name LanmanServer -Force
```

Finally perform `chkdsk /F c:` and `chkdsk /F d:` and `sfc /scannow` then `reboot` the server... check those registry entries again, you will find them correctly written..

To add more about traoubleshooting this issue, I also tried closing MDT console, and I ran the following on powershell:

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.BDD.PSSnapIn
Get-MDTPersistentDrive
Remove-MDTPersistentDrive DS00x
```

Which also did not work. Then I deleted all the deployment shares, rebuilt them, with no success. The only way things worked for me was to delete those registry entries as described earlier. I also removed and isntalled MDT many times, also with no success...

Hope this helps, because non of the solutions I found while googling worked for me.